# How to make expandale only one row in ui-grid table

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I use ui-grid in my project.

I am  using [expandable](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) feature in ui-grid.

I need to make expandable only one row.

For example, if I click on '+' sign on row number 5 and then I click on '+' sign on row number 2 the row number 5 have to be closed and row number 2 have to be expanded.

Any idea how can I implement this behaviour in ui-grid?

Comment: There must be something strange with your plunker, I cannot open it

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the following api from the expandable feature:

- `rowExpandedStateChanged`

This is an event raised whenever the expanded state is changed and can be used to intercept the user expanding another row.

- `toggleRowExpansion(rowEntity)`

This can be used upon receiving the event to close any other expanded row.

Inside your code you should add this row inside of your `gridOptions.onRegisterApi`

```
gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged(scope,function(row){})
```

Where function is a custom function where you scroll all the rows in the grid, check whether they are expanded or not by checking `row.isExpanded` and close every expanded row (but the one the user just expanded, obviously).

Just a reminder, as the team stated on the website, beware that the expandable feature is still in a alpha stage.

Comment: I am getting  $scope.gridApi.selection.toggleRowExpansion is not a function error while calling toggleRowExpansion($scope.gridApi.grid.selection.lastSelectedRow.entity)

Answer (score 1):

Overwrite main functionality to making angular UI Grid force to expand only one row at a time when expand/collapse bottom clicked..

search "toggleRowExpansion" inside ui-grid.js and then:

```js
toggleRowExpansion: function (rowEntity) {

// --------- COMMENT THIS LINES: ---------

// var row = grid.getRow(rowEntity);
// if (row !== null) {
// service.toggleRowExpansion(grid, row);
// }


// --------- ADD THIS LINES: ---------

var row = grid.getRow(rowEntity);
   if (row !== null) {
   var isRowExpanded = row.isExpanded || false;
   service.collapseAllRows(grid);
   if(!isRowExpanded) service.toggleRowExpansion(grid, row);
   }
}
```